Why is the admin user becoming a member of newly created role in Postgres?
I am quite new to PostgreSQL. We have a database server on Azure Postgres Flexible Server. I log in to that server using the admin credentials, dmsadmin. Then I create a new role using the command, CREATE ROLE dev_user1. Now running the \du, gives me the following output ->
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |                                                           Member of                                                           
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 azure_pg_admin    | Cannot login                                               | {pg_read_all_data,pg_monitor,pg_read_all_settings,pg_read_all_stats,pg_stat_scan_tables,pg_checkpoint,pg_create_subscription}
 azuresu           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 dev_user1         |                                                            | {}
 dmsadmin          | Create role, Create DB, Bypass RLS                         | {pg_read_all_settings,pg_read_all_stats,pg_stat_scan_tables,azure_pg_admin,dev_user1}
 replication       | Replication                                                | {pg_use_reserved_connections}

Now if I understand the output correctly, it says that dmsadmin is a member of dev_user1. So I tried to remove that membership using the command REVOKE dev_user1 FROM dmsadmin. Then I got the following warning:
WARNING:  role "dmsadmin" has not been granted membership in role "dev_user1" by role "dmsadmin".

How is that possible?
Thank you in advance.

That must be some Microsoft hack. PostgreSQL doesn't automatically make you a member of a role you create. I guess that grant was made by a system user. Look at SELECT roleid::regrole, member::regrole, grantor::regrole FROM pg_auth_members WHERE roleid = 'dev_user1'::regrole;.

I see this:
roleid   |      member       | grantor 
-----------+-------------------+---------
dev_user1 | dmsadmin | azuresu

It seems like azuresu is granting that membership. I wil try to set role as azuresu and try to remove the member

You won't be able to do that, because that is a superuser. I guess Microsoft wants to force you to be a member of all roles you create. Perhaps they will change that in v16, no idea.

I have same situation on Azure Flexible Server v16 which is not the case in Azure Single Server v11, there is no relationship between the users you create using a user. Also have noticed more related issues
